# Create different disconnected graphs from a set of fixed nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, graph-theory

I have the following set of nodes:

`n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

Using `networkx` package, I want to create 4 random connected graphs where each contain 5 nodes from the above list in such a way that the label of the node should appear in the newly formed graph.

For example:

`subgraph_1 = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17]`

`subgraph_2 = [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]`

`subgraph_3 = [3, 7, 11, 15, 19]`

`subgraph_4 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]`

Is there a way to accomplish this using the built in packages functions of networkx? I could not locate anything in the documentation.

Another way that this could work is that, I can create a random graph with 20 nodes using: `G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=20,p=0.1)` but then I would be needing to divide this into random 4 subgraphs with each one having 5 nodes. The edges can be regenerated randomly and do not have to be linked or similar to the edges of the main graph `G`.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that that is by creating 4 random networks of size 5 using the `nx.erdos_renyi_graph` function. For each network, you can randomly pick without replacement 5 nodes from your vector `n` and relabel the nodes of the network with the random nodes.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=20
n=np.arange(N)+1

#randomly permuting nodes
random_n=np.random.permutation(n)

N_graphs=4
N_nodes=5
#assign the random modes to each graph
random_graphs_nodes=[random_n[N_nodes*i:N_nodes*(i+1)] for i in range(N_graphs)]

#create random graphs
r_g=[nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=N_nodes,p=0.5) for _ in range(N_graphs)]

#relabel the nodes in each graph according to random_graphs_nodes
mappings=[]
for i in range(N_graphs):
  mappings.append({j:str(random_graphs_nodes[i][j]) for j in range(N_nodes)})
  r_g[i]=nx.relabel_nodes(r_g[i], mappings[i]) 

#plot result
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
colors=['tab:blue','tab:orange','tab:green','tab:pink']
for i in range(N_graphs):
  plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
  plt.title('Graph '+str(i+1))
  pos=nx.circular_layout(r_g[i])
  nx.draw(r_g[i],pos=pos,with_labels=True,node_color=colors[i])
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jylls, this seems to work fine for me. Perhaps, I made a small edit to the question regarding the new graphs to be connected.

Comment: Fair enough! Are you interested in generating fully connected graphs (each pair of disjoint nodes are connected by an edge). Or just connected as in: all nodes are reachable from all the other nodes?

Comment: No, not fully connected, just connected, as in all nodes are reachable from another node.